# Toggle with no id's so multiple will open on same page

Tags: click, toggle, jquery

Basically I need multiple toggles to open on the same page without opening all at once or only allowing one to open at a time.  Users have awards below their avatar that I want to hide/show however I want to be able to click on multiple users awards and see them all while on the same page.

I know I'm not suppose to use ID's since I want more than one per page to open however I'm not sure how to redo the code without them.

jQuery:

```
function toggle() {
var ele = document.getElementById("awardtoggle");
var text = document.getElementById("showcontent");
if(ele.style.display == "block") {
        ele.style.display = "none";
    text.innerHTML = "";
}
else {
    ele.style.display = "block";
    text.innerHTML = "";}}
```

HTML:

```
<a id="showcontent" href="javascript:toggle();"><div class="awards">Award Box</a></div><div id="awardtoggle" style="display:none; margin-top:-83px;"><!-- |awards| --></div>
```

CSS:

```
.awards {position: relative; top:-65px; text-align: center; background: #444642; color: #fff; text-transform: uppercase; font-family: Oswald; font-size: 10px; padding: 2px; line-spacing: 2px;} .awards a:link { color: #fff;} .awards a:visited { color: #fff;} .awards a:hover, .awards a:active {color: #fff;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do something like

```
<a class="showcontent" href="#">
    <div class="awards">Award Box</div>
</a>
<div class="awardtoggle" style="display:none; margin-top:-83px;">
    <!-- |awards| -->
</div>
```

then

```
jQuery(function(){
    $('.showcontent').click(function(e){
        $(this).next().toggle();
        e.preventDefault();
    })
})
```

Comment: The toggle function with that didn't work at all. I modified it slightly and I still couldn't get it to work. When you click it to show it just scrolls to the top of the screen.

Comment: @user2790524 sorry missed to prevent the default action